# Scraping Webpages with Javascript-loaded <select> options

Tags: javascript, python, html

I am trying to use Python's mechanize module to submit an HTML POST form request. To do so, I must select an option from a <select> element, but the options are loaded dynamically by Javascript.

Since I know the <select> option I want to use, I tried to construct the form request using the not-yet-loaded option value, doing something like:

```
browser.find_control(name="formName", kind="list").value = ["optionValue"]
```

However, mechanize raises an ItemNotFoundError because it deems the value as invalid. Additionally, I try to append to the listvalue, the option value I want and then set it, but this also does not work. Any idea how to fix this problem and set a control to a Javascript loaded value?

Comment: Looking at the code, the control has a `.items` property which is a list. You'll need to work out what type of objects need to go in there. https://github.com/jjlee/mechanize/blob/master/mechanize/_form.py#L1576 . Or if you know all the required values, skip mechanize for the form and just make the POST request directly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you did this already, but when you try to append the option to the `<select>` list, use the more cumbersome `document.createElement`,`parentNode.appendChild` methods from javascript instead of `innerHMTL=...`, jQuery `html(..)` or jQuery `$('<..>..</..>')`, which do not always work fully or correctly (e.g. in your case perhaps).

The dynamic loading of the options can also insert a token (e.g. [csrf](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)) into a hidden field in the form, which must be included in the post. In that case you will have to trigger or wait for the loading of the options before creating the post.